# Jquery Interdependencies with radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm new to [jquery interdependencies](https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies). What's the proper way to use it with radio button selection? In this example I'm trying to display Question 2A if "A" is selected, and Question 2B if "B" is selected.

html:

```
<div>
   <span>Question 1</span>
   <input type="radio" id="radioQ1" name="firstQuestion" value="answerA">A<br>
   <input type="radio" id="radioQ2"  name="firstQuestion" value="answerB">B
</div>

<div id="Q2A">
   <span>Question 2A</span>
   Etc. etc. etc.
</div>

<div id="Q2B">
   <span>Question 2B</span>
   Etc. etc. etc.
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start creating a new ruleset
    var ruleset = $.deps.createRuleset();

    var myRule2A= ruleset.createRule("#radioQ1", "==", "answerA");  //also tried "true" (without quotes)
    myRule2A.include("#Q2A");

    var myRule2B = ruleset.createRule("#radioQ2", "==", "answerB");
    myRule2B.include("#Q2B");

    // Make the ruleset effective on the whole page
    ruleset.install({log: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

JS

```
 var myRule2A = ruleset.createRule("#radioQ1", "==", true);
 myRule1.include("#Q2A");

 var myRule2B = ruleset.createRule("#radioQ2", "==", true);
 myRule1.include("#Q2B");
```

Comment: hi i am also using jquery-inter and i am trying to check the value of a hidden value but it seems only "==", true works and not "==", "value-i-set" Do you know how to check against a string value?